# C++ object constructor pass by const reference copying

Tags: c++, reference, constructor, copy, constants

When I pass an object to another object as a const reference, is there a copy made? I always assumed since I passed in the object by reference the member object itself was actually the object I passed in and not a copy. I made a test program that causes the passed in reference object to be destroyed at the end of scope, but it doesn't crash as I expected. Is this a bug waiting to happen or is the object getting copied?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class Something
{
public:
    Something(const std::string& str) : mStr(str) {}
    const std::string& str() const
    {
        return mStr;
    }
private:
    std::string mStr;
};

int main()
{
    Something* something;
    {
        std::string temp = "Testing.";
        something = new Something(temp);
    }

    std::cout<<something->str()<<"\n";
    delete something;
    return 0;
}
```

Is that std::string still valid or is it deleted? (In the object itself)

Comment: To proper test that behaviour, you should use not std::string but objects of classes that you wrote on your own. you are testing std::string, not behaviour at the moment!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data member `mStr` is of type `std::string` (it's an object, not a reference).

Therefore, when you initialize it in the constructor's initialization list (via `: mStr(str)`), the argument, which was passed by reference, is *copied*.  In your example, only the initialization causes a copy to be made:  if you removed the initialization, no copies would be made.

Comment: Would assignment in the constructor body cause copying?

Answer (score 3):

Contents of `temp` variable is copied to `mStr`. The code is valid.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, except you are missing the fact that mStr(str) makes a copy of str.  This copy is destroyed in ~Somthing();